# GPS not receiving location updates when device goes to sleep(black screen)

Tags: java, android, gps

I am facing a problem, I have an activity that tracks users location. It's for tracking outdoor activities but, when the device goes to sleep the GPS stops sending location updates to my LocationListener.

How can I solve this ? Or what is the proper implementation ?

I have read that partialwakelock is the solution so I followed the instructions and added a partialwakelock into oncreate and realeas in ondestroy but this had no effect on it.

Then the other proposed solution was to have a foreground location service that would send those location updates to my activity for processing. But that seem to be too complex and there is a chance of the service being destroyed which is not acceprable. even though I could restart it but still.

What is the proper implementation ?
I would do it with a foreground service if necessary but anyways, I need someone who has some experience here..

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Use a ForegroundService and instruct the user to remove any battery optimization for your application in the device's settings. (They may vary by manufacturer.)

Comment: _"proposed solution was to have a foreground location service [...] a chance of the service being destroted"_ ForegroundServices are actually much less likely to be destroyed than anything else. _"kind of spaghetti code.."_ It's not spaghetti code if you do it right. :)

Comment: Thanks Markus this was actually what I needed to hear.. it can be that the battery optimization can block the updates on sone dev8ces, apparently the newer ones because if I remember it good it used to work on my old phone..

Comment: I can do it with a foreground service and register a receiver in case the service gets stopped and restart it in my activity.. because outdoor hikes etc. can last quite some time.. system may shut it down who knpws..

Comment: I have tried that implemenration and it works ..thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service for it to get continue location without activity

```
   import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public static double latitude;
    Context ctx;
    Location location;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    public static double longitude;
    MyLocationListener(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "GPS Enable " + isGPSEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Network Enable " + isNetworkEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    ( ctx, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION )
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( ctx,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  }
            if (isGPSEnabled == true) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,     0,       0, this);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (isNetworkEnabled==true) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,    0,     0, this);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            // Toast.makeText(ctx,"latitude: "+latitude+" longitude: "+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Toast.makeText(ctx,"Exception "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        //print "Currently GPS is Disabled";
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        //print "GPS got Enabled";
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }
}
```

To use that class add this method location is stored in the Address string

```
public void getLocation(){
    Double latitude = 0.0, longitude;
    String message = "";
    LocationManager mlocManager = null;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

        latitude = MyLocationListener.latitude;
        longitude = MyLocationListener.longitude;
        message = message +"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/@"+ latitude +","+  longitude;
        address=message;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (latitude == 0.0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Currently gps has not found your location....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is currently off...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have redundant code. The `getLocation()` method requests location updates and creates an instance of `MyLocationListener` which also requests location updates. Wouldn't it be enough for the `MyLocationListener` to just listen to the location updates? Also `loc.getLatitude();` and `loc.getLongitude();` in `onLocationChanged()` don't do anything useful. (Just some observations.)

Comment: @ Markus Kauppinen, We can guide here, but cant provide ready code as per the question need, It is easy to handle further process after using this answer

Comment: Thanks guys.. I will do ot with a foreground service even though I don't like this approach.. beauty in simplicity..